# Windows - service account default certificate store

Tags: windows, certificates, certificate-authority

I am writing a web app that connects to external web services. The external web services serve an intermediate certificate signed by `Thawte SGC CA - G2`.

When I setup IIS to run the web app using service account on a separate corporate domain (let's say, `DEV\service_account`), the application fails to validate the certificate because it doesn't trust the CA. However, when I use my own account, there is no such problem.

A look into the machine and my account certificate stores shows that `Thawte SGC CA - G2` isn't in any of `Personal`, `Intermediate` or `Trusted Root CA` stores.

How then, does my account decide that the certificate can be trusted?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the intermediate certificate (`Thawte SGC CA - G2`) needs to be downloaded off of Thawte's site. And the reason why the service account couldn't establish the trust is because it's not allowed to download the certificate.